# Scala: specifying a generic type that is constructible from another

Tags: scala

I would like to do something which, more or less, boils down to the following:

```
def foo[S](x: String): S = S(x)     // S(x) does not compile
```

So that if I have:

```
case class S1(x:String)
case class S2(x:String)
...
case class Sn(x:String)
```

I can write `foo[Sx]("bar")` to get `Sx("foo")`.

Is there any way to specify that an instance of a class should be constructible from an instance of another (in this example String) and to actually invoke the constructor in a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may use reflection (see @Ben Reich answer for detailed answer)

   ```
   def foo[S:ClassTag](x: String): S = { 
     val runtimeClass = implicitly[ClassTag[S]].runtimeClass
     val constructor = runtimeClass.<get a constructor with single String argument>
     constructor(x) .asInstanceOf[S]
   }
   ```
2. Or a type class that can construct an instance:

   ```
   trait CanConstruct[S] {
     def apply(x:String):S
   }

   def foo[S:CanConstruct](x: String): S = { 
     val constructor = implicitly[CanConstruct[S]]
     constructor(x).asInstanceOf[S]
   }
   ```

   **UPD** You would need an instance of the type class for every type you wish to construct:

   ```
   implicit val s1constructor = new CanConstruct[S1] { def apply(x:String) = S1(x) }
   ...
   ```
3. Also it seems to be the case for conversion functions:

   ```
   implicit val convertStringToS1 = S1(_)
   implicit val convertStringToS2 = S2(_)
   ...
   ```

Comment: I have tried the second alternative: `case class Foo(s:String); val bar = foo[Foo]("bar")` but it does not compile. (Unspecified value parameter evidence$1)

Comment: You need an implicit instance of `CanConstruct` for every type you wish to be able to construct.

Comment: So it seems my choice is between reflection or boilerplate :-( ... or maybe macros?

Comment: @Eduardo You can also use structural types, but I don't think anyone would recommend them.

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection:

```
import reflect.ClassTag

def foo[S: ClassTag](x: String) = implicitly[ClassTag[S]]
    .runtimeClass
    .getConstructors
    .map(a => a -> a.getParameters)
    .collectFirst { 
        case (constructor, Array(p)) if p.getType == classOf[String] 
            => constructor.newInstance(x).asInstanceOf[S] 
    }
```

Which will return an `Option[S]`, if the proper constructor is found.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved it with a macro:

```
object Construct {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def construct[A,B](x:B):A  = macro constructImpl[A,B]

  def constructImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag,B](c:Context)(x:c.Expr[B]) = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[A](q"""new ${c.weakTypeOf[A]}(${x.tree})""")
  }
}
```

I now can write things like:

```
case class Foo(x:String)
case class Bar(x:Int)

construct[Foo,String]("foo")
construct[Bar,Int](42)
```

It would be nice to find a way to avoid having to write the second type parameter, though.